# Tokenfield for Bootstrap can not get "click" event when delete a token

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tokenfield

I want to get "click" event when i want to delete a token using Tokenfield for Bootstrap. I only can get "click" event for existing token but not dynamically generated one.

```
// working for existing token
$('.close').on('click', function(){
    alert('OK!');
});

// not working
$(document).on('click', 'a.close', function(){
    alert('delete');
});
```

Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rns3hang/13/) for details.

Comment: if you make the not working one use just the class like the one that is working, does that work? `.close` instead of `a.close`?

Comment: not working for that way too.

Comment: your fiddle works for me, if I add a color then click submit it shows that I added the color and if I click the `x` on that color and then click the submit it is removed and displays the correct colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its normal, you create a new element of dom. But your $('.close') is already initialized.

So you can try to do something like that:

See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rns3hang/14/

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
      autocomplete: {
        source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
        delay: 100
      },
      showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
    });

    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.form-data').text( $('#tokenfield').val());
    });
    close();


});

function close() {
    $('.close').on('click', function(){
                alert('OK!');
        });

    $(document).on('click', 'a.close', function(){
         alert('delete');
        });

}

$('input').change(function() {
close();
})
```